# Getting multiple errors while Installing Scipy

Tags: python, opencv, pip

I'm not able to install Scipy on my Raspberry Pi Model B.

My current setup is:

- Raspberry Pi model B running Raspbian Jessie and 16gb SD card.
- OpenCV 3.1.0 installed on the raspberry pi using this [tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/).
- Python 2.7.9 installed on the RPi

I tried using  `pip install Scipy` and have also tried `pip install scikit-image` without any luck. Here is the screenshot of the error I got:

[image]

The main warning that seems to get repeated is:

> warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by"

I have installed matplotlib and numpy successfully on my Raspberry Pi, it only fails while installing Scipy.

I then tried `sudo apt-get install python-scipy` and it installed Scipy version 0.14.0-2 successfully, however I am unable to import the module. I get the following error:

> No module named scipy

Is there a fix for this? I'm not sure why Scipy is repeatedly failing to download.

Comment: please do not post screenshots. Redirect the relevant output to a file and post the contents of the file, properly formatted.

Comment: If you have time to reinstall OpenCV, follow up my [tutorial](https://github.com/Tes3awy/OpenCV-3.0.0-Compiling-on-Raspberry-Pi-2-). I don't use Virtual Environment for installing OpenCV. Just change the version to be 3.1.0 as yours.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if your problem is that you are running old packages and modules please update your pi using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and tell me if it solves your problem.